AWS BATCH: Container Overrides length must be at most 8192
We are trying to start an AWS batch job. The job definition has over 40 parameters which are referenced in the command (example below).
When starting a batch job we get an error
Container Overrides length must be at most 8192. 

What is causing this issue? Is there a work around this issue? Can the limit be increased?
Parameters: {
  "command": "output",
    ...
  }
ContainerProperties:
   Command:
   - python3
   - main.py
   - --command
   - Ref::command
   ...

A solution we've come up with involves uploading some of the larger parameter values to S3. And have the batch job download the data when it runs. Which seems to work. But still wondering if there is a native aws batch approach to solving this, perhaps can the limit be inceased?
